# Downloading XML and adding to the database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need to write a script that will download the XML from FTP copied files to the server that will be added to the database by the script. The problem is that I do not know if it is possible to connect to the server where the database is placed and copy files to a folder from which they can be downloaded?

The database is installed on synology MariaDB 10 (localhost via UNIX socket).

```
<?php
$ftp_serwer            = "xxx";
$ftp_nazwa_uzytkownika = "xxx";
$ftp_haslo             = "xxx";

// nawiązanie połączenia lub zakończenie działania skryptu
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_serwer) or die("Nie można połączyć się z $ftp_serwer");

// próba logowania
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_nazwa_uzytkownika, $ftp_haslo)) {
    echo "Połączony jako $ftp_nazwa_uzytkownika@$ftp_serwer\n";
} else {
    echo "Nie można zalogować się jako $ftp_nazwa_uzytkownika\n";
}


// nawiązanie połączenia z baza danych msql

$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "zlecenia";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3307);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


// define some variables
$local_file = 'Z:\htdocs\phpmysql\TEST\CRM\localfile\yahootable.xml';
$server_file = '/TU WGRYWAC DANE/yahootable.xml';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_serwer);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_nazwa_uzytkownika, $ftp_haslo);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}




$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
    'Z:/htdocs/phpmysql/TEST/CRM/localfile/yahootable.xml'
INTO TABLE 
    yahootable
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
LINES STARTING BY '<row>' TERMINATED BY '</row>'
(@tmp)
SET
  id      = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//id'),
  various = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//various'),
  message = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//message')

";



// zamknięcie połączenia
ftp_close($conn_id);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

So my questions are:

1. Where do I have to upload a file so that the server can download it using
   `LOAD DATA INFILE`?
2. How to copy files to this folder using a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `LOCAL` keyword in your `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command it will load the file from the host where the MySQL client is running, as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html:

> If `LOCAL` is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.

The MySQL client in your case will be the host which runs the php script. The path has to be accessible by **that** host and will automatically be transferred to the MySQL server.